# Voting on-topic questions off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

At least a couple of people openly [voted a question today as off-topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/23074/101), despite noting that they considered it on-topic here as well.

After I posted about this in the chat, @hippietrail suggested I mention it here too, that if a question is on-topic on two sites, even if you think it's better on the other one, this is NOT a reason to vote it as off-topic.

From Meta.SO: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250)

[image]

> It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple
>   sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere. The OP asked
>   their question here, so if it's on-topic here, then it should stay
>   here.

Of course, if you truly feel a question is actually **off-topic** on travel.SE, then of course, do vote as such.

Comment: enter image description here!!

Comment: What's precisely the question here??? I have the impression that you are just lobbying in favour of one of your posts.

Comment: Not at all, like I said, if it's off-topic, close it as off-topic. But as you and hippie said it could be either, I'm just pointing out that you don't close on-topic questions, even if they're 'better' on another site, as hippie suggested I post it here, given that he didn't realise, and that you might not. There's more in the chat.