# Too many off-topic flags?

Tags: discussion

I've never looked at the close-votes queue till today.

Of nine posts, more than a third were flagged off-topic though I thought they were quite obviously appropriate for Travel.

Is this a common occurrence?

Related but not duplicate: [Voting on-topic questions off-topic](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/voting-on-topic-questions-off-topic)

Comment: Can you cite some examples? Voting to close is one thing; for a question actually to be put on hold requires five experienced users to agree. It may be that you are simply more forgiving than others.

Comment: I didn't say on hold.  Vote to close review queue.  I cannot cite them because the queue is now empty.  But several of them were unmistakeably on-topic.  And one was flagged "unclear what you're asking" when it fact it was VERY clear.  First time I ever looked at that particular queue, so I just wonder whether that was a common pattern.  Maybe somebody got up on the wrong side of the bed and took it out on Travel.SE

Answer (score 2):

I spend a lot of time in the review queues and usually find that flagging is appropriate.  I wonder sometimes just how opinion-related a question needs to be to be closed - that's about the only area where things get really ambiguous for me.  I tend to give those questions the benefit of the doubt, as giving some discussion of options and merits is a useful exercise for future readers, even if there is some subjectivity afoot.

I tend to flag quite a few posts myself for transfer over to Expatriates, but I find they tend to be pretty obvious.